# How to manually breaks, label, and specific colours in continous variable with geom_sf fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some maps with geom_sf (with about 200k polygons). My sf object has a continous column called `'preds'`  that varies from -1.8 to +1.6. The object also is separated in years in a column called `'Year'` The relevant bits are only negative, zero, and positive values. So, what I'm looking for is to present maps that only show negative, zero and positive (<0 ; 0 ; >0) as red, blue, and green or something. I've tried the code bellow but R is not happy with me.
There is a filter in the process, but that shouldn't be causing issues, I think.

```
 map_pred %>%
  filter(variable == 'onlythisone') %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Preds), lwd = 0)+
  facet_wrap(. ~ Year)+
  scale_fill_continuous(breaks = c(-2,0,2), labels = c("< 0", "0", "> 0"))
```

Edit: I've tried to use fill_gradient but I still get a gray map :(

```
map_pred %>%
      filter(variable == 'onlythisone') %>%
      ggplot()+
      geom_sf(aes(fill = Preds), lwd = 0)+
      facet_wrap(. ~ Year)+
      scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-1.5,1.5),
                        low = 'red', high = 'green',
                        breaks = c(-1,0,1),
                        labels = c("-1", "0", "+1"))
```

Thanks everyone, I cannot post a sample of the data. I appreciate the help, nonetheless.

Comment: Maybe just a typo?  It should probably be `geom_sf` instead of `geom_df`.

Comment: Lol, well spotted, but I've re-wrote here so I still get a gray map instead the colours that I wanted. I've update the code for a different thing that I tried.

Comment: not reproducible without sample data... Please add a *minimal* dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to accomplish your expected result with an example dataset (below), which suggests an issue with the structure of your input data. Like others are saying in the comments, please post a subset of your data so we can help.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc$Preds <- runif(10, min = -2, max = 2)
nc$Year <- sample(c(2010, 2011, 2012), nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)

nc %>%
  filter(AREA > 0.05) %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(aes(fill = Preds), lwd = 0) +
      facet_wrap(.~Year) +
      scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green",
                          limits = c(-1.5, 1.5),
                          breaks  = c(-1, 0, 1),
                          labels = c("-1", "0", "1"))


Created on 2022-04-05 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Unfortunatelly, I can't share a sample of the data.